# Shipping Modules FedEx and USPS stopped working with upgrade from magento 1.8.1 to 1.9.0.1 CE

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I upgraded from Magento CE 1.8.1 to 1.9.0.1 and now the FedEx and USPS shipping modules I had set up do NOT work, as in they do not show in the shipping step at checkout.

At first I thought it might be a Theme / Template issue since I am finding that virtually ALL of the Themes that I have tried, that worked fine with 1.8.1 have problems somewhere with 1.9.0.1 so I set it to the RWD Default theme that was part of the 1.9.0.1 Magento CE install, but it did not fix the shipping problems.

I was using the following in 1.8.1 with no problems:

Free Shipping
FedEx
USPS
UPS

Now the only two I can get to work are UPS and Free Shipping.  The UPS module is really not that great as it does not factor return accurate shipping values.

Any help would be appreciated.  ( I have cleared the cache and have tried enabling / disabling the shipping options to no avail.)

---

If this is not the best place to ask for help, is there another Magento help forum or board besides the one at the Magento site http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards ? It looks like questions go for days or even WEEKS with no response over there.  I have googled and came up with nothing that looks promising as far as "unofficial" magento forums. It is almost like ebay is somehow hiding the other forums! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found this on a fresh install when I was missing the php-soap extension.  The page would return me to the cart, and the following showed in the error logs:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SoapClient' not found in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php on line 134

```
yum install php-soap
```

and then

```
service httpd restart
```

This may, or may not be the issue you are facing?